# what do you call someone who cannot tell the difference between right and wrong/love and hate?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that describes someone who cannot tell the difference between love and hate, or right and wrong.

**NOT** "innocent", I am looking for a different connotation.

Comment: Do you ask for an adjective which describes a person that cannot distinguish love from hate? or right from wrong? something like naive or immature or something like bad judgment?

Comment: Try the word *blind*.

Comment: A philosopher...a sophist.

Comment: This seems to be more of a psychology question. You might ask on Cognitive Sciences SE.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Personally, I call him _Dave._

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a "bad person" (difference between right and wrong not being relevant to them), then you could go with sociopath or psychopath.

Someone who can not tell the difference between love and hate would definitely be either naive like a child, or a sociopath/psychopath (manipulative/controlling behaviors are spiteful/hateful but described as loving by such people).

If you're not talking about a "bad person", then naive would best fit.

Answer (score 0):

The perfect fit, in my opinion, would be

> **naive**

which is loosely defined as -

> showing a lack of experience, wisdom, or judgement